# How to get the output from python script using pythonnet in .net core 3.1?

Tags: python, c#, .net-core, python.net

I'm trying to execute python script using pythonnet and I want to know is there any method to get the returned output to use it somewhere else?

the python script is like this:

```
import sectionproperties.pre.library.primitive_sections as sections
from sectionproperties.analysis.section import Section

geometry = sections.circular_section(d=50, n=64)
geometry.plot_geometry()

geometry.create_mesh(mesh_sizes=[2.5])

section = Section(geometry, time_info=True)
section.display_mesh_info()
section.plot_mesh()

section.calculate_geometric_properties()
section.calculate_warping_properties()
section.calculate_plastic_properties()

section.display_results()

(ixx_c, iyy_c, ixy_c) = section.get_ic()
j = section.get_j()
print("Ixx + Iyy = {0:.3f}".format(ixx_c + iyy_c))
print("J = {0:.3f}".format(j))
```

I already have tried to use process to run the python script but it didn't give the full output of the script.

when using process the generated output is:

```
MULTIPOLYGON (((-2 0.375, -0.5625 0.375, -0.5625 1.8125, 0.5625 1.8125, 0.5625 0.375, 2 0.375, 2 0.5625, 0.75 0.5625, 0.75 2, -0.75 2, -0.75 0.5625, -2 0.5625, -2 0.375)), ((-2 0, 2 0, 2 0.375, -2 0.375, -2 0)))
Mesh Statistics:
- 2038 nodes
- 926 elements
- 2 regions

+---------------------------- Geometric Analysis -----------------------------+
|                                                                             |
|
```

But when I run this script on python it gives this output:

```
MULTIPOLYGON (((-2 0.375, -0.5625 0.375, -0.5625 1.8125, 0.5625 1.8125, 0.5625 0.375, 2 0.375, 2 0.5625, 0.75 0.5625, 0.75 2, -0.75 2, -0.75 0.5625, -2 0.5625, -2 0.375)), ((-2 0, 2 0, 2 0.375, -2 0.375, -2 0)))
Mesh Statistics:
- 2038 nodes
- 926 elements
- 2 regions


┌──────────────────────────── Geometric Analysis ─────────────────────────────┐
│                                                                             │
│   ✅ Geometric analysis       --------------------------- 100% [ 2.3120 s ] │
│   complete                                                                  │
│                                                                             │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────────────────── Warping Analysis ──────────────────────────────┐
│                                                                             │
│   ✅ Warping analysis         -------------------------- 100% [ 12.2180 s ] │
│   completed                                                                 │
│   ✅ 2038x2038 stiffness      -------------------------- 100% [ 2.7350 s ]  │
│   matrix assembled                                                          │
│   ✅ Warping function solved  -------------------------- 100% [ 0.0310 s ]  │
│   (direct)                                                                  │
│   ✅ Shear function vectors   -------------------------- 100% [ 2.7030 s ]  │
│   assembled                                                                 │
│   ✅ Shear functions solved   -------------------------- 100% [ 0.0630 s ]  │
│   (direct)                                                                  │
│   ✅ Shear and warping        -------------------------- 100% [ 2.1250 s ]  │
│   integrals assembled                                                       │
│   ✅ Shear deformation        -------------------------- 100% [ 2.4840 s ]  │
│   coefficients assembled                                                    │
│   ✅ Monosymmetry integrals   -------------------------- 100% [ 2.0620 s ]  │
│   assembled                                                                 │
│                                                                             │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────────────────── Plastic Analysis ──────────────────────────────┐
│                                                                             │
│   ✅ Plastic analysis         --------------------------- 100% [ 0.0940 s ] │
│   complete                                                                  │
│                                                                             │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Section Properties
┌──────────┬───────────────┐
│ Property │         Value │
├──────────┼───────────────┤
│ A        │  2.789062e+00 │
│ Perim.   │  1.200000e+01 │
│ Qx       │  1.626709e+00 │
│ Qy       │ -3.204902e-16 │
│ cx       │ -1.149096e-16 │
│ cy       │  5.832458e-01 │
│ Ixx_g    │  1.935211e+00 │
│ Iyy_g    │  3.233734e+00 │
│ Ixy_g    │ -3.022756e-16 │
│ Ixx_c    │  9.864400e-01 │
│ Iyy_c    │  3.233734e+00 │
│ Ixy_c    │ -1.153510e-16 │
│ Zxx+     │  6.962676e-01 │
│ Zxx-     │  1.691294e+00 │
│ Zyy+     │  1.616867e+00 │
│ Zyy-     │  1.616867e+00 │
│ rx       │  5.947113e-01 │
│ ry       │  1.076770e+00 │
│ phi      │ -9.000000e+01 │
│ I11_c    │  3.233734e+00 │
│ I22_c    │  9.864400e-01 │
│ Z11+     │  1.616867e+00 │
│ Z11-     │  1.616867e+00 │
│ Z22+     │  1.691294e+00 │
│ Z22-     │  6.962676e-01 │
│ r11      │  1.076770e+00 │
│ r22      │  5.947113e-01 │
│ J        │  9.878443e-01 │
│ Iw       │  1.160810e-01 │
│ x_se     │  4.822719e-05 │
│ y_se     │  4.674792e-01 │
│ x_st     │  4.822719e-05 │
│ y_st     │  4.674792e-01 │
│ x1_se    │  1.157666e-01 │
│ y2_se    │  4.822719e-05 │
│ A_sx     │  1.648312e+00 │
│ A_sy     │  6.979733e-01 │
│ A_s11    │  6.979733e-01 │
│ A_s22    │  1.648312e+00 │
│ betax+   │ -2.746928e-01 │
│ betax-   │  2.746928e-01 │
│ betay+   │  9.645438e-05 │
│ betay-   │ -9.645438e-05 │
│ beta11+  │  9.645438e-05 │
│ beta11-  │ -9.645438e-05 │
│ beta22+  │  2.746928e-01 │
│ beta22-  │ -2.746928e-01 │
│ x_pc     │ -1.149096e-16 │
│ y_pc     │  3.486328e-01 │
│ Sxx      │  1.140530e+00 │
│ Syy      │  2.603760e+00 │
│ SF_xx+   │  1.638062e+00 │
│ SF_xx-   │  6.743533e-01 │
│ SF_yy+   │  1.610373e+00 │
│ SF_yy-   │  1.610373e+00 │
│ x11_pc   │  2.393564e-16 │
│ y22_pc   │  3.486328e-01 │
│ S11      │  2.603760e+00 │
│ S22      │  1.140530e+00 │
│ SF_11+   │  1.610373e+00 │
│ SF_11-   │  1.610373e+00 │
│ SF_22+   │  6.743533e-01 │
│ SF_22-   │  1.638062e+00 │
└──────────┴───────────────┘
Ixx + Iyy = 4.220
J = 0.988
```

```
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
            psi.FileName = @"python.exe";

            var script = @"script.py";

            psi.Arguments = $"\"{script}\"";
            psi.UseShellExecute = false;
            psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
            psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
            psi.LoadUserProfile = true;

            var errors = "";
            var results = "";

            using (var process = Process.Start(psi))
            {
                errors = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
                results = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                process.WaitForExit();
            }
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "didn't give the full output"? What output did you get, and what output were you expecting?

Comment: @Brian61354270 I've edited the question to include the returned and expected output